# UIColors always have 3dp, but floats have 6. This causes problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point, uicolor

I have a number in a float that I want to put into a UIColor as a hue. It does it just fine, but when i go to use that later, the app crashes because of it. How can i make it so when it goes into UIColor, it's only got 3dp?

Comment: We need to see some code. I don't know how it'd be possible for an app to crash because of a float, nor how a float's precision will cause problems with `UIColor`.

Comment: that, plus you shouldn't try to use `UIColor` as a container for your own values. E.g. when you make a black color using `r=g=b=0.0f` iOS might decide to drop the RGB colorspace for this `UIColor` object in favor of a grayscale colorspace. Good luck debugging that!

Comment: Agreed with BoltClock. It almost sounds like you're trying to parse strings instead of retrieving the actual component values.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", floatToMake3DP];

float threeDP = [string floatValue];
```

I think that the above is the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't what Andrew meant, though of course, he'll have to clarify further to get a better answer.